# Setting EditText.Text outside OnCreate

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a very simple application, currently only containing two classes - these are "**MainActivity.cs**" and "**NewDate.cs**"

MainActivity simply hooks up a button and an editText control, then makes a call to "**NewDate.NewTimer()**" - this just begins a .NET timer instance.

Inside "OnCreate" I am able to set the value of the EditText successfully when the user clicks the button, however, when the timer expires, I call

```
     SafeDate.MainActivity.SetTimerDoneText("Timer done!");
```

Using breakpoints I can determine that the application is running through "SetTimerDoneText", but the line

```
 editTimerInfo.Text = Text;
```

does not work.

Any help would be greatly apprecioated.

Both classes below:

MainActivity.cs

```
 public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    static EditText editTimerInfo;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        Button btnNewTimer = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.newDate);
         editTimerInfo = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTimerInfo);
        btnNewTimer.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // Translate user's alphanumeric phone number to numeric
            Core.NewDate.NewTimer();
           // editTimerInfo.Text = "Timer started!"; //this works
        };
    }

    public static void SetTimerDoneText(string Text)
    {
        //SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);//commented out - doesn't work
        //   EditText editTimerInfo = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTimerInfo); //commented out - doesn't work
        editTimerInfo.Text = Text;
    } 
}
```

NewDate.cs

```
public static class NewDate
{

    public static void NewTimer()
    {

        System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Interval = 5000; //Miliseconds : 5000 = 1 second
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    // Specify what you want to happen when the Elapsed event is raised.
    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        SafeDate.MainActivity.SetTimerDoneText("Timer done!"); //Successfully enters the function in MainActivity.cs but won't set the EditText value
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using so much `static` keywords ? Are you sure you understand what they do ?

Comment: Well I need to access most of the things that I've declared as static from outside. I'm a VB.NET developer just trying to get to grips with Xamarin so I understand the .NET framework well but some of the C# syntax I'll admit is a bit lost on me. In the Xamarin documentation & basic tutorials they've declared lots of stuff static.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you are basically trying to implement a ViewModel pattern.

Since you are a beginner, this may be a bit complex to grasp, but when you are ready, take a look at [some tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm)

From now on, go for something much more simple, and put your logic in your Activity

```
btnNewTimer.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    aTimer.Interval = 5000; //Miliseconds : 5000 = 1 sec
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
};

private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    editTimerInfo.Text = "Timer done!"; //Successfully enters the function in MainActivity.cs but won't set the EditText value
}
```

I have never played with `Timers` so I cannot guarantee it will work, but this is already better than using statics.

Check if this works for you